# Get the line number of the last line with non-blank characters

Tags: awk, sed, wc

I have a file which has the following content:

```
10 tiny toes
tree
this is that tree
5 funny 0
```

There are spaces at the end of the file. I want to get the line number of the last row of a file (that has characters). How do I do that in SED?

Answer (score 2):

This is easily done with `awk`,

```
awk 'NF{c=FNR}END{print c}' file
```

With `sed` it is more tricky. You can use the `=` operator but this will print the line-number to standard out and not in the pattern space. So you cannot manipulate it. If you want to use sed, you'll have to pipe it to another or use `tail`:

```
sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*$/!=' file | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following pseudo-code:

```
Replace all spaces by empty string
Remove all <beginning_of_line><end_of_line> (the lines, only containing spaces, will be removed like this)
Count the number of remaining lines in your file
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to count line numbers in sed.  Some versions of sed give you the `=` operator, but it's not standard.  You could use an external tool to generate line numbers and do something like:

```
nl -s ' ' -n ln -ba input | sed -n 's/^\(......\)...*/\1/p' | sed -n '$p'
```

but if you're going to do that you might as well just use awk.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you  (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/\S/=' file | sed -n '$p'
```

For all lines that contain a non white space character, print a line number. Pipe this output to second invocation of sed and print only the last line.

Alternative:

```
grep -n '\S' file | sed -n '$s/:.*//p'
```